# Supremum and infimum of $S=\{x|x^2 \leq 7\}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Quoting: Find the supremum and infimum of $S=\{x|x^2 \leq 7\}$. State whether they are in S.

Given $$x^2 \leq 7 $$
      $$  \sqrt{x^2} \leq \sqrt{7}       $$
$$ |x| \leq \sqrt{7}$$
$$- \sqrt{7} \leq x \leq \sqrt{7}$$

It shows that $- \sqrt{7}$ and $\sqrt{7}$ are a lower bound and upper bound of S respectively

As $- \sqrt{7}$ is the greatest lower bound and $\sqrt{7}$ the least upper bound,

Infimum of S: $$inf(S)=- \sqrt{7}$$
supremum of S:$$ sup(S)= \sqrt{7}$$

Both are contained in S

Is this enough to declare that both inf and sup are contained? Is there a more efficient approach?

Any input is much appreciated

Comment: You approach looks good to me.

Comment: Are $x$ real numbers?

Comment: I really need to know the context of your course and the purpose of the exercise.  That is indeed the correct answer but have you demonstrated the $\sqt {7} $ always exists and is meaningful concept.  How clear is it supposed to be that the extrema of {x| a <= x <b} are a and b?  Yes, these are basic and obvious concepts but often the point of a class is to systematically and rigorously nail down these ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give an argument that they are contained, instead of just claiming it: Since $(\sqrt7)^2 \le 7$ and $(-\sqrt7)^2 \le 7$, both are contained in S.

The argument for finding the infimum and the supremum is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If $S \subset \mathbb Q$ you won't find $\pm \sqrt7$ in it.